# How to create a list of pairs out of each key and all its individual values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
dict = { a: 1,2,3
         b: 4
         c: 7, 8}
```

I want to create a list that looks like this

```
list [a1, a2, a3, b4, c7, c8]
```

in python

ive tried creating a for loop but it just concatenates all the values with a single key and thats not what I want.

Comment: It is **not** a proper `dict`. Can you post `print(dict)`? Meanwhile, please post what you have tried as well.

Comment: A dict can't have multiple values for the same key. Post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) first.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing [more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4], 'c': [7, 8]}
new_d = [f'{a}{i}' for a, b in d.items() for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b4', 'c7', 'c8']
```